# Matching REGEX strings

Tags: regex

I have two groups of strings listed below. I need two REGEX expressions: one that matches all strings in the first group (the first five lines) and none in the second group, and then the second REGEX expression that does the opposite (match all strings in the second group but none in the first group). I've spent hours trying to figure this out and cannot.

```
RUNERL-MJ09N6S3
RUNSHISBOY231D1
RUNSTA-CJ0312SD
RUNEOITHIL122D1
RUNPSPACPS100L1

RUNPSPACPS100S1
RUNSDEAHIL508S1
RUNEOITHIL122S1
RUNCOITHIL122S1
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the general rules, that the regexes should contain. Also show what you have tried! SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to come up with a more clever general solution, if you know what these strings represent and there is some pattern. But with the given info this should work.

```
regex1 = /(RUNERL\-MJ09N6S3|RUNSHISBOY231D1|RUNSTA\-CJ0312SD|RUNEOITHIL122D1|RUNPSPACPS100L1)/
regex2 = /(RUNPSPACPS100S1|RUNSDEAHIL508S1|RUNEOITHIL122S1|RUNCOITHIL122S1)/
```

Comment: I've been working with this:

^(RUN[^STA].*S.)$

The problem is that it only ignores the first letter in the bracket which is S. I want it to ignore the entire string STA.

Comment: I am testing the REGEX at the regextester.com website and doesn't give me the desired results.

Comment: Basically, the requirement is to catch anything that begins with RUN and ends with S and a number at the end, except things that begin with RUNERL and RUNSTA.  Sorry for the multiple posts but the forum doesn't let me edit after 5 minutes.

Comment: Do you consider `D` as a digit?

Comment: @Armali D is a letter.

Comment: @user319563 - With the _requirement_ in your comment above you defined _the second group_. The _opposite_ of that would be everything else, including e. g. the empty string or `anything`. So, what do you want for the first expression: (a) the plain and simple opposite, or (b) something that matches strings like those _in the first group_? If (b), you'd have to define also the requirement for that.